# how to make my message count command count messages for each server, not all in once

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I make my message count command count messages for each server? But not all at once because I want to have it like when I type +messages on the server it count form only this when I use this on the other server it count from other server only.

```py
messageCount = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    author = str(ctx.author)
    if author in messageCount:
        messageCount[author] += 1
    else:
        messageCount[author] = 1
    
    await client.process_commands(ctx)
 
@client.command()
async def messages(ctx: commands.Context, *, user: discord.User=None):
    """To see how many messages are being sent by the user"""
    user = user or ctx.author
    msg = messageCount.get(str(user))
    if msg:
        await ctx.send(f"{user} sent about {msg} in total")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user} didn't sent any message yet"
```

here is code of my coommand

Answer (score 0):

Following your current implementation that only counts the amount of messages sent since latest bot startup, you could use nested dictionaries. Your new `messageCount` directory should have server IDs for keys and the old `messageCount` directories as values. Pseudocode:

```py
messageCount = {
    Server1: {
        User1: 5,
        User2: 7
    },
    Server2: {
        User1: 3,
        User3: 4
    }
}
```

When checking the message counts, first `.get()` the server in the outer dictionary, and only then search for the user. You can use `ctx.guild.id` to get server IDs.